# Generic event handler not firing from dynamic buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a bunch of buttons being dynamically created and setting its click event to an event handler...When I run it they handler in never firing, I've stepped through the code and nothing seems out of the ordinary but it just won't fire.

Here is a snippet of the code where the button is being created..

```
for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 9; cellCtr++)
            {

                Button button = new Button();

                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();

                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

                if (rowCtr == rN)
                    break;

                string myStr = daccess.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr]["SubjectName"].ToString();
                int myID = Convert.ToInt32(daccess.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr]["SubjectID"].ToString());

                button.ID = Convert.ToString(myID);
                button.Text = myStr;

                button.CssClass = "btn btn-primary btn-sm"; 

                button.Click += ButtonSubjectClick;

                tCell.Controls.Add(button);

                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                rowCtr++;

                if (cellCtr == rN)
                {
                    rowCtr = rowCtr - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

and here is the handler that's it suppose to call...

```
void ButtonSubjectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        daccess.DeleteSubjects(Int32.Parse(button.ID.ToString()));
        button.CssClass = "btn-active";  
    }
```

When its ran, the source looks like this

```
<input type="submit" name="38" value="Math" id="38" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
```

Comment: Did you try making `ButtonSubjectClick` a static method? I'm basing it on the samples from MSDN, haven't been able to try myself.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't think I did. I had this issue before and I figured out the answer, but I can't find out what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // do something if needed
    }

    // outside of postback, you need to add it each time
    Button button = new Button();
    button.ID = "btn1";
    button.Text = "clicky me";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonSubjectClick);
    pnl.Controls.Add(button);
}

void ButtonSubjectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    button.Text = "clicked me";
}
```

I believe it's a question about how are you adding your button to the page. I'm adding my button at each postback and it is thus registered by the server.

If you are adding your buttons in another event then you could use viewstate or session variables, store some kind of a flag to create the button and then check for this flag in each postback.

Edit, for the sake of clarity, pnl is a Panel on my page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm creating these buttons on a button click..I.E I have 6 buttons, and each button when clicked, generates its respective buttons with values from my database, and when any of those dynamic buttons are clicked its supposed to run its handler to delete that record

Comment: Yes, but you have to make sure those buttons are added to the control tree on each page load,which includes when those dynamic buttons are clicked.

Comment: (replying to OP, Hardrada is correct) This won't work as the buttons are generated too late in the page lifecycle so when you click one the server does not know about this button and it disregards its click event. The best solution would be as I indicated in my post; on the originating button click make a sesssion variable ie. Session["createBtn1"] = "yes"; and then in Page_Load ask yourself if (Session["createBtn1"] != null) then create this button.